# django form not rendering in template. Input fields doesn't shows up

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I'm not able to see the django form in my template. it is not being rendered properly. I've tried working on this, but the form not shows up. Tried the same code in a new project to test-that worked fine but here it doesn't work. This {{ form.as_p }} not shows up anything i.e. no input fields for me to enter the details and check the other part. Thanks in advance.

```
# forms.py

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    contact_subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    content = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea
    )`
```

and:

```
# views.py

def contact(request):
    form_class = ContactForm

    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get(
                'contact_name'
            , '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get(
                'contact_email'
            , '')
            contact_subject = request.POST.get(
                'contact_subject'
                , '')
            form_content = request.POST.get('content', '')

            # Email the profile with the
            # contact information
            template = get_template('contact_template.txt')
            context = Context({
                'contact_name': contact_name,
                'contact_email': contact_email,
                'contact_subject' : contact_subject,
                'form_content': form_content,
            })
            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage(
                "New contact form submission",
                content,
                "Your website" +'',
                ['youremail@gmail.com'],
                headers = {'Reply-To': contact_email }
            )
            email.send()
            return redirect('contact')

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {
        'form': form_class,
    })
```

The template for the same looks like this.

## template

```
 <section id="contact">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="bg-image">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center share-text wow animated zoomInDown heading-text">
                        <p class="heading">
                            If you got any questions, please do not hesitate to send us a message.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

                {% block content %}
                <h1>Contact</h1>
                <form role="form" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
                {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Please add the rest of your view. I.e: what happens if `request.method == "GET"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an else clause for generating a form on GET:

```
def contact(request):

    form_class = ContactForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)
        # ... more code from above ...
    else:
        form = form_class() # this is important

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {
        'form': form,  # NOTE: instead of form_class!!!!
    })
```

Comment: making these changes didn't help. only the heading contact n the submit button is visible. Else nothing in between. @Udi

Comment: Check again. make sure to fix the call to render(). check your file names, typos, etc. add something to your context: `{'form': form, 'foo': 'BAR'}` and see if you can see it from your template with `{{foo}}`

Comment: No it is not getting rendered. I tried adding {'foo' : 'bar'} to my context. i can't see the same in my template with {{ foo }}.

Comment: Check the names of your files. Stop your server, and make sure it is stopped from the browser and start it again.

Comment: I created a new html file for the same. pasted the code for form over there and the same works. I've the actual contact form on my index page. It is not getting rendered over there.

Comment: Which view is rendering your index page? You will have to add `return render(request, 'index.html', {
        'form': ContactForm()
    })` there too.

Comment: Ok. I wasn't knowing that. Thank You so much.

Comment: Your'e welcome. Make sure to specify `<form action="{% url ... %}" ....>`  to post the data to the other view as well

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the form class to your template instead of a form instance.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't handled the case when `request.method` is not `POST`.

Your view should look like this:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # form handling logic here
            # ...
            # ... 
            return redirect('some-link')
        else:
            return render(request, 'template.html', dict(form=form))
    else:
      form = ContactForm()
      return render(request, 'template.html', dict(form=form))
```

Comment: making these changes didn't help. only the heading contact n the submit button is visible. Else nothing in between. @gitblame